# Change the color of a PNG image (and still preserving transparency) using HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, png

Good Evening,

Is there a way to change the color of a png image (and still preserve the transparency) using html/css?

The new color can be anything in the rgb spectrum. The image in question is a vector drawing but I can't use SVG and the fill property.

Comment: You can do this with a CSS mask.  I hope that addresses your question.

Comment: Like Viper said, use a mask.. By the way, how do you have a vector png!?

Comment: TRy using filters. Check this out:
https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/FXTF/raw-file/tip/filters/index.html#FilterFunction

http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html